# Ionic3 fetching the promise value

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, promise

I am a newbie of IONIC. I have one simple problem that I could not use promise value for my typescript class. It is returning the object but I need the value. Otherwise one of my conditions doesn't fulfill. Can anyone guide me how can be used this promise value into typescript class? Code is

app.component.ts

```
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';
import {SocialActivitiesPage} from '../pages/social-activities/social-activities';
import { HomeTabsPage } from '../pages/home-tabs/home-tabs';
export class MyApp implements OnInit {
  rootPage:any = TabsPage;
  socialProfile:any = SocialActivitiesPage;
  hometabs:any = HomeTabsPage;

@ViewChild('nav') nav:NavController;

  constructor(platform: Platform, 
      statusBar: StatusBar, 
      splashScreen: SplashScreen,
      public menuCtr:MenuController,
      private storage: Storage,) {

  }
  token:Promise<any> = this.storage.get('token').then((val)=>{
    return this.token = val; 
  }).catch(
    (err)=>{
      console.log(err);
    }
  )

  ngOnInit(){
    if(this.token!==null){
      this.rootPage = HomeTabsPage; 
    }
  }
  ionViewDidLoad(){
    console.log(this.token);
  }

}
```

Above code is my app.component.ts where I resolved my token promise by below this

```
token:Promise<any> = this.storage.get('token').then((val)=>{
    return this.token = val; 
  }).catch(
    (err)=>{
      console.log(err);
    }
  )
```

And tried to make one condition into ngOnInit()

```
  ngOnInit(){
    if(this.token!==null){
      this.rootPage = HomeTabsPage; 
    }
  }
```

unfortunately here this condition is not working. Whether my token is null or not null. Here this.token is one object, not any value. But If I call this token from app.html it returns as a string value, not an object. I tried to call this token into app.html like this way

```
{{token}}
```

It is showing the string value. Unfortunately, from the typeScript class, it is always showing my one object that has some `_zoneSymboleType` and `_zoneSymboleValue`. Here in `_zoneSymboleValue` I can see my value. So my question How can I use this.token as a value, not as an object into my typeScript conditions. 

It would be highly appreciated your effort. 

Thanks

Comment: you want to retrieve the data that is in `token`?, or you are doing only verification with it?

Comment: Where you set the token?

Answer (score 1):

This is asynchronous, so it takes a while for the response to arrive, you can resolve this by calling that function in your `OnInit` instead:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.storage.get('token').then((val)=>{
    if(val!==null){
      this.rootPage = HomeTabsPage; 
    }
  })
}
```

Read more about async: [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)

Comment: You are awesome Man! Working like a charm. Could you please tell me one tinny hint that This functions works after refreshing the whole App, otherwise It goes the previous state. Should I use ionViewDidLoad() or windows.location.reload(). And I heard about that windows.location.reload() function doesn't work on mobile. So What would be the optimal solution for this? @AJT_82

Comment: I'm having a bit trouble understanding here. You want what to happen when you refresh? :) Or do you mean that you want to refresh? :)

Comment: I am really sorry, `this.rootPage=HomeTabsPage` is changing from my app.html `<ion-nav #nav [root]="rootPage" ></ion-nav>`
If token is not null it will change the my nav Footer from rootPage = TabsPage to this.rootPage = HomeTabspage.So that If my user does login  then my `this.rootPage= HomeTabsPage` will be changed according to token logic. I am pushing my HomeTabsPage from my `Singin()` method. This one is last part of  my Signin() methods `this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomeTabsPage)`.For changing this I need to write `window.location.reload()`